# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I have been researching but haven't found a reasonable way to fix the issue. All I'm trying to do is create a new table in MySQL Workbench but keep getting the 1064 error with a message >> Syntax error: unexpected `user_mapping_id` (back tick quoted id). Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_mapping` (
  `user_mapping_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data_type_user_data` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_mapping_id`)
);
```

Comment: Works for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ba2b

Comment: worked for me in workbench...

Comment: Looks like removing the back ticks worked. I had almost the exact same create table sql with a different table name and fields. Just this one kept giving me an issue. Thanks for your help !